# How to use auth-user-pass other then giving file path in OpenVPN config

Tags: c#, openvpn

i am working around with OpenVPN everything working fine but i dont want to give login credentials in cofig or the path of file in config due to security reasons. Is there any way to pass these credentials to openvpn process directly or any way where i dont need any file or any written line to save them for authentication ??

Regards